# Entity Framework throwing error when updating records

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

`Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.`

I get this error, but I am the only person using the database.  I am using Entity Framework 4.1 with DBContext.

I am updating my records and SQL Profiler is showing a queue being sent in.  What could be the causes of this issue?

The post:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult EditUser(User user)
  {                 
       uow.UserRepository.Update(user);
       uow.Save();
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");

  }
```

On this call:

```
  public void Save()
  {
        _context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

This is how it is attached

```
  public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
  {
         dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
  }
```

Update:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private StudentSchedulingEntities _context = new StudentSchedulingEntities();
    private GenericRepository<User> userRepository;
    private GenericRepository<UserRole> userRoleRepository;
    private bool disposed = false;

    public GenericRepository<User> UserRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.userRepository == null)
            {
                this.userRepository = new GenericRepository<User>(_context);
            }
            return userRepository;
        }
    }
    public GenericRepository<UserRole> UserRoleRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.userRoleRepository == null)
            {
                this.userRoleRepository = new GenericRepository<UserRole>(_context);
            }
            return userRoleRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you are trying to run when this happens.

Comment: The code is fairly straight forward.  It pulls the DB object on the view and sends in a post.  In the SQL profiler seems to see all the variables and changes, but I get that error.

Comment: do you by any chance have open connection to the user db both in your controller and uow ?. i.e do you instantiate dbContext in your controller and your repository?

Comment: I added some code to show how I'm persisting the data.  I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: In your `EditUser` action the `user` parameter has the right ID?

Comment: nemesv, you were right.  I had two IDs with similar names where I confused which was missing.  I forgotten the hidden field that did not post.  If you put an answer, I'll verify as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID field must be there in order to update the information properly.  Otherwise, it will be throw a null.  (I forgot to put the hidden field for ID in)